# Haskell function with deck of playing cards (returning value of hand)

Tags: list, haskell, playing-cards

i am in revision week and i am trying to work on a past paper for Haskell exam. However, this function is something i can't quite cope with.

The values of playing cards are represented like this:
  ’2’, ’3’, ’4’, ’5’, ’6’, ’7’, ’8’, ’9’, ’T’, ’J’, ’Q’, ’K’, ’A’.
 A hand of cards can be written as a String, for example “A563Q”.

I need to to write a function 
scoreHand :: [PlayingCardValue] -> Int
that will return the total value held in a hand of cards. ’A’ has a value of 11. ’T’, ’J’, ’Q’ and ’K’ each have a value of 10. The other numbers have their face value (’2’ has a value of 2, ’3’ has a value of 3 and so on).

So i am supposed to write two versions of this function. **First one** using recursion and no library functions or list comprehension and **second one** the other way around (a.k.a) using list comprehension, library functions etc.

**I wrote the version with recursion, but i am struggling with the other 
version.**

Here is my code with recursion (even though i'm using one library function, but i will figure it out eventually)

*

```
import Data.Char
type PlayingCardValue = Char
scoreHand :: [PlayingCardValue] -> Int
scoreHand [] = 0
scoreHand (x:xs) =
  if x > '1' && x < '9'
    then digitToInt x + scoreHand (xs)
    else if x == 'T' || x == 'J' || x == 'Q' || x == 'K'
      then 10 + scoreHand (xs)
        else if x == 'A'
          then 11 + scoreHand (xs)
          else 0 + scoreHand (xs)
```

*
Any ideas on how to create the same function not using recursion?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `x <= '9'`, instead of `x < 9`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all I think you can make the code more elegantly, by introducing a *new* function:

```
score :: PlayingCardValue -> Int
score '2' = 2
score '3' = 3
score '4' = 4
score '5' = 5
score '6' = 6
score '7' = 7
score '8' = 8
score '9' = 9
score 'T' = 10
score 'J' = 10
score 'Q' = 10
score 'K' = 10
score 'A' = 11
score _ = 0
```

So now we can calculate the score of an individual card. We can use the [**`digitToInt :: Char -> Int`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:digitToInt) function if we want. It is also more clean how the score of a single card is calculated.

Next we can use recursion with:

```
scoreHand :: [PlayingCardValue] -> Int
scoreHand [] = 0
scoreHand (x:xs) = score x + scoreHand xs
```

If we want to write a non-recursive one, we can make use of [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map), and [**`sum :: Num a => [a] -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum):

```
scoreHand :: [PlayingCardValue] -> Int
scoreHand xs = sum (map score xs)
```

So by using `map score xs`, we create a new list, where for each card in the list `xs`, we have an element that contains the score, and then we `sum` up these values. We can write it more elegantly, by using function composition:

```
scoreHand :: [PlayingCardValue] -> Int
scoreHand = sum . map score
```